# In Lebesgue's characterization of measurability, why is the set required to have finite outer measure?

Tags: measure-theory, solution-verification, lebesgue-measure, outer-measure

In Chapter $2$ of Royden, #$20$, we are asked to show **for a set $E$ of finite outer measure** that $E$ is measurable if and only if  for each open bounded set $(a,b)$ we have $m^*((a,b))=b-a=m^*((a,b)\cap E) + m^*((a,b)\sim E).$ Note we define $E$ to be measurable if $E$ satisfies Carathéodory's splitting condition.

I have a clear proof, but nowhere did I invoke that $E$ is finite in outer measure. Where is that assumption used in this problem?

For completeness, here is my proof:

Clearly if $E$ is measurable then the claim follows since if we take $A=(a,b)$ in the definition of measurability of a set $E$ then

\begin{equation}
    \begin{split}
        m^*(A)& = m^*((a,b))\\
        & = b-a\\
        & = m^*((a,b)\cap E) + m^*((a,b)\cap E^C)\\
        & = m^*((a,b)\cap E) + m^*((a,b)\sim E)
        \notag
    \end{split}
\end{equation}
where the second equality follows from the outer measure of an interval being its length, the third equality follows from the substitution of $A=(a,b)$ into the definition of a measurable set, and finally the fourth equality follows from the set identity $(a,b)\cap E^C=(a,b)\sim E.$ Now we assume for every open bounded interval $(a,b)$ we have
\begin{equation}
    m^*((a,b))=b-a=m^*((a,b)\cap E)+m^*((a,b)\sim E)\tag{1}
\end{equation}
We want to show $E$ is measurable assuming $(1)$. We thus need to show for every set $A$ of finite outer measure that
\begin{equation}
    \begin{split}
        m^*(A)& \geq m^*(A\cap E) + m^*(A\cap E^C)\\
        & = m^*(A\cap E) + m^*(A\sim E).
        \notag
    \end{split}
\end{equation}
By definition of $m^*(A)$ as the infimum, we need only show that for any countable open cover of $A$ by bounded nonempty open intervals $\{I_k\}_{k=1}^\infty$ we have $$\sum_{k=1}^\infty m^*(I_k)\geq m^*(A\cap E) + m^*(A\sim E).$$ Note
\begin{equation}
    \begin{split}
        A&\subseteq \bigcup_{k=1}^\infty I_k\implies\\
        A\cap E&\subseteq \bigcup_{k=1}^\infty(I_k\cap E)\\
        \notag
    \end{split}
\end{equation}
and
\begin{equation}
    \begin{split}
        A\cap E^C&=A\sim E\\
       &\subseteq\bigcup_{k=1}^\infty (I_k\cap E^C)\\
       & = \bigcup_{k=1}^\infty (I_k\sim E).
        \notag
    \end{split}
\end{equation}
Observe we have for each $I_k=(a_k,b_k)$ assuming $(1)$ that $$m^*(I_k)=b_k-a_k=m^*((a_k,b_k)\cap E)+m^*((a_k,b_k)\sim E),$$ so since $A$ has finite measure the sum is convergent and thus $$\sum_{k=1}^\infty m^*(I_k)=\sum_{k=1}^\infty m^*(I_k\cap E)+\sum_{k=1}^\infty m^*(I_k\sim E).$$ We have by the countable subadditivity and monotonicity of the outer measure that
\begin{equation}
    \begin{split}
        \sum_{k=1}^\infty m^*(I_k)&=\sum_{k=1}^\infty m^*(I_k\cap E)+\sum_{k=1}^\infty m^*(I_k\sim E)\\
        & \geq m^*\left(\bigcup_{k=1}^\infty (I_k\cap E)\right) + m^*\left(\bigcup_{k=1}^\infty (I_k\sim E)\right)\\
        & \geq m^*(A\cap E) + m^*(A\sim E).
        \notag
    \end{split}
\end{equation}
Thus $m^*(A)\geq m^*(A\cap E) + m^*(A\cap E^C)$ holds, and hence $E$ is measurable. $\blacksquare$

Comment: I think that when you write "We have by the countable additivity and monotonicity of the outer measure..." , you mean "We have by the countable sub-additivity and monotonicity of the outer measure...".

Comment: You are right. The result is true even if $E$ has infinite outer measure.  Your proof is fine. Another way of seeing that the result holds even if $E$ has infinite outer measure is to prove that if $E$ is ANY set satisfying the condition *"for each open bounded set $(a,b)$ we have $m^*((a,b))=b-a=m^*((a,b)\cap E) + m^*((a,b)\sim E)$"*, then, for all $c \in \Bbb Z$, $E \cap (c,c+1)$ also satisfies the same condition. So, for all $c \in \Bbb Z$, $E \cap (c,c+1)$ is measurable. So $E$ is measurable.

Comment: @Ramiro thank you! That makes sense. Yes I did mean 'sub' additivity instead.